# ¿Cómo aplico una transaccion en PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo este archivo con una conexión, dentro de ella hay una función query.

¿Cómo aplico una transaccion en ella?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
date_default_timezone_set('america/bogota');
setlocale(LC_ALL, "es_ES@euro", "es_CO", "esp");
class server
{

    private static $db_host = 'localhost';
    private static $db_user = '';
    private static $db_pass = '';
    private $db_name        = '';
    private $conexion;
    private $resultado;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conectar();
    }

    protected function conectar()
    {

        $this->conexion = mysqli_connect(
            self::$db_host,
            self::$db_user,
            self::$db_pass,
            $this->db_name);

        if (!$this->conexion) {
            mysqli_error($this->conexion);
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    protected function query($sql)
    {
        $this->resultado = mysqli_query($this->conexion, $sql);
        if (!$this->resultado) {
            die('error: query ' . mysql_error());
        }

    }

    protected function extraerRegistro()
    {
        $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->resultado);
        return $fila;
    }

    public function affected()
    {

        $num = mysqli_affected_rows($this->conexion);
        if ($num) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Cabe recalcar que en un archivo llamado model tengo una serie de funciones que hacen el llamado de ese metodo query() para realizar los CRUD  necesarios.

Answer (score 1):

Para el uso de transacciones [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli.php) provee varias varias funciones que puedes implementar en función de tus necesidades.

- `mysqli::begin_transaction`, inicia una transacción.
- `mysqli::commit`, consigna una transacción.
- `mysqli::rollback`, revierte una transacción.

> **NOTA:** El uso de transacciones requiere MySQL 5.6 o superior y el motor InnoDB.

Un ejemplo básico de su uso:

```
// se asume conexión en $mysqli

// creamos una bandera
$result_transaccion = true;

// iniciamos transacción 
$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);

// realizamos las querys
if( !$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('DEU', 'Bavarian', 'F', 11.2)") ) {
    // registramos el fallo
    $result_transaccion = false;
}

if ( !$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Language VALUES ('DEU', 'Swabian', 'F', 9.4)") ) {
    // registramos el fallo
    $result_transaccion = false;
}

if($result_transaccion) {
    // consignamos
    $mysqli->commit();
} else {
    // revertimos
    $mysqli->rollback();
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: si tengo esto $this->conexion como hago el llamado de commit(); ya que asi $this->conexion->commit(); me genera error.

Comment: Qué error te da?

Comment: la captura de errores esta mal, suponiendo que la primera consulta falla la variable quedaría así  `$result_transaccion = false;` pero la segunda transacción si se inserta y cambiaria a true, entonces se insertaría la segunda transacción sin importar que la primera se inserte.
No se estaría capturando bien los errores.
Una opción seria que la variable  `$result_transaccion`  sea un array y preguntar si en el array se encuentra un 0 o un false ejemplo
`if (in_array(0, $result_transaccion)) {
   // revertimos
    $mysqli->rollback();
}else {
  // consignamos
    $mysqli->commit();
}`

Comment: @deimer si falla alguna ninguna de las 2 se confirma, la segunda no se confirma, no hay nada que las cambie a true. El array es innecesario. Puedes hacer la prueba tu mismo.